# How to produce a negative decimal from a string using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to create a negative decimal from a string ie:

Currently I have code that works well for positive decimal as such:

```
var decimalList = Regex.Split("£100.00", @"[^0-9\.]+").Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "");
decimal decimalValue = decimal.Parse(decimalList.First());
```

Which results in 100.00

```
var decimalList = Regex.Split("X-100.00X", @"[^0-9\.]+").Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "");
decimal decimalValue = decimal.Parse(decimalList.First());
```

Which should result in -100.00 which is the point of this question.

How do I change the Regex to cope with negative values ie: "-1.2" and maintain the negative in the resulting decimal.

Thanks.

Comment: The current regex in `Regex.Split` does nothing to `"100.00"`, but would remove `-` from `"-1.2"`. What is the purpose of the split?

Comment: Sorry I will elaborate in my question.... The current removal of "-" is an issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd use `var match = Regex.Match(s, @"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+")` then would check `if (match.Success)` and if yes, parse `match.Value`.

Comment: Justing trying that, thanks.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/BOO2WY

Comment: You are a star, that works well. If you put it as answer then I can mark it. So much appreciate your prompt and quality answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a *matching* approach would be easier here. A pattern to match a float/integer-like values is `-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`, and with `Regex.Match`, you can extract the first occurrence of the pattern in a string. Then, just parse the value found:

```
var s = "X-100.00X";
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+");
if (match.Success) {
    decimal decimalValue = decimal.Parse(match.Value);
    Console.Write(decimalValue);
}
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/BOO2WY).

**Pattern details**:

- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits.

Comment: Marvellous... Thanks

Comment: I took out the `+`, I guess you do not need it. See [the online regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-%3f%5b0-9%5d*%5c.%3f%5b0-9%5d%2b&i=120.455+1.344+-24.445+3454+0+111).